# How to distribute binaries via pip

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I know that sounds a bit of a mad thing to do, but pip is probably the most likely-to-be-installed package manager in many cases, and also CMake does it (`pip install cmake` is by far the easiest way to get an up-to-date build of CMake on Linux and Mac).

But anyway how would I actually do it? As far as I can tell from [the wheel spec](https://peps.python.org/pep-0491/), wheels can include "scripts" that don't have to be Python scripts (it could be a native executable). Also wheels can be platform-specific, so I can put my Linux x86 binary in one wheel, Mac ARM one in another, upload them all to PyPI and pip will figure it out.

But how do I actually do that? I got as far as creating a `pyproject.toml` with a `[project.scripts]` entry, but it appears that those entries *do* have to be Python scripts.

The questions are:

1. Is this possible already (e.g. using `setuptools`, `python -m build`, etc.)?
2. If not, is this possible *in theory* (if I write my own builder)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems like this is definitely possible. There is a Rust project called [Maturin](https://github.com/PyO3/maturin) that builds wheels from Rust code. I think it's really designed for Python libraries that are thin wrappers around Rust libraries, but it also supports installing binaries as scripts. [Here is an example.](https://github.com/PyO3/maturin/tree/main/test-crates/hello-world)

I'm not sure what you'd do if your project wasn't a Rust project, but fortunately mine is. I guess take a look at the Maturin code to see what it does.